# Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at /home/runner/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm

when I run this command in github actions:

```
npm install -g pnpm 
pnpm add -g pnpm
pnpm install
pnpm run build
```

the github actions shows error:

```
Run npm install -g pnpm 
  npm install -g pnpm 
  pnpm add -g pnpm
  pnpm install
  pnpm run build
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    CI: false
  
added 1 package in 1s
npm notice 
1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.3 -> 10.4.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.4.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.4.0` to update!
npm notice 
Nothing to stop. No server is running for the store at /home/runner/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3
 ERR_PNPM_NO_GLOBAL_BIN_DIR  Unable to find the global bin directory
Run "pnpm setup" to create it automatically, or set the global-bin-dir setting, or the PNPM_HOME env variable. The global bin directory should be in the PATH.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?